# Get Google Form Response Printable URL via Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, url, google-forms

In Google Forms, it's possible to print a single response.

[image: Screenshot pointing out the Print button on a Google Forms response]

This opens a new tab with a URL such as:

```
https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/1VqMbpn69qCApBZKXzbjmjxz1TLQ8VyxR-2aC2WqO2z8/printresponse?viewresponse=ACYDBNhGZ47ckBgoyjBgpb_r9sVdxYlo10w6MoLTV0zP
```

The response ID at the end of the URL seems to differ from the ID that you get from [`FormResponse.getId()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getid), since the following does **not** work:

```js
let printUrl = FormApp.getActiveForm().getEditUrl().replace('/edit', '/printresponse?viewresponse=') + FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponses()[0].getId();
```

How do I get this "print response URL" via Apps Script?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the response ID from the UI is **different** from both ID's fetched from `FormResponse.getID()`, `FormResponse.getEditResponseUrl()`, or `FormResponse.toPrefilledUrl()`.

The closest you can get from Apps Script is either [`getEditResponseUrl()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#geteditresponseurl), which needs `Allow Response Edits` option to be enabled, or [`toPreFilledUrl()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#toprefilledurl), which generates the same response that you can submit.

[image]

Comment: So there's no way to get the `/printresponse?viewresponse=ACYDBNhGZ4...` URL in Apps Script?

Comment: Unfortunately it cannot be get from Apps Script.